# Oracle forms cursor issue

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, oracleforms

I am using Oracle Forms and facing issue in writing a cursor. My cursor is

```
   CURSOR ss
   IS
        SELECT pjno, bdate, PROJECT
          FROM billcrown
               LEFT JOIN bank_details ON billcrown.pjno = bank_details.pjno
         WHERE billcrown.bdate > '01-Jul-2017'
      GROUP BY billcrown.pjno
        HAVING SUM (billcrown.PAMT) <> NVL (SUM (bank_details.AMOUNT), 0);

   s   ss%ROWTYPE;
```

It's showing error on pining on left join.
Error is (Encountered the symbol 'JOIN' when expecting one of the following. , ; )
 It is working fine at SQL prompt. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which Forms version is it? If it complains on `LEFT JOIN`, that's probably 6i or something. Previous (very old) Forms versions' PL/SQL engine didn't quite follow database's PL/SQL engine so not everything, that worked in the database, worked in Forms as well.

Therefore, I'd suggest you to try with the old Oracle outer join operator, (+).

Furthermore, if `BDATE` column's datatype is `DATE`, you should use `DATE` values against it, not strings. `'01-Jul-2017'` is a string. `DATE '2017-07-01'` is date (literal).

Finally, saying that your code works fine in SQL*Plus - no, it is not. `GROUP BY` contains only c.pjno column, so `bdate, PROJECT` should be included in there as well (or you should rewrite that query).

Something like this:

```
   CURSOR ss
   IS
        SELECT c.pjno
          -- , bdate, PROJECT                 --> removed because of the GROUP BY clause
          FROM billcrown c, bank_details d
         WHERE c.pjno = d.pjno (+)            --> this
         and c.bdate > date '2017-07-01'      --> use dates, not strings!
      GROUP BY c.pjno
        HAVING SUM (c.PAMT) <> NVL (SUM (d.AMOUNT), 0);
```

Comment: I haven't tried Forms 12c yet, but the ANSI join syntax still didn't work in Forms as of Forms 11g.  I'm hoping it will work in 12c, which we're migrating to sometime soon (within a year).